# Detectron2 what is difference between INPUT.MIN_SIZE and INPUT.MAX_SIZE

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, image-resizing, detectron

In detectron2 training, in the config we can define the `INPUT.MIN_SIZE` and `INPUT.MAX_SIZE` to tell detectron what image resolution to scale to in terms of width(height is determined by Detectron2). I understand this scaling is done by Edge shortest size function.

My question is what is the difference between these two variables and how do they work in this function?

Let's say I have training image of 1280 x 720 but also training images of 2560 x 1440. I want to scale all images to minimum of 1280 x 720 so I would put `INPUT.MIN_SIZE(720,)`. What would I populate the max variable then with and how would the algorithm handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is exactly as it says in `ResizeShortestEdge` [documentation](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data_transforms.html#detectron2.data.transforms.ResizeShortestEdge):

> It attempts to scale the shorter edge to the given *short_edge_length*, as long as the longer edge does not exceed *max_size*. If *max_size* is reached, then downscale so that the longer edge does not exceed *max_size*.

You can also see this [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/48b598b4f61fbb24182a69b521b2a0ba3252b842/detectron2/data/transforms/augmentation_impl.py#L176) in the source code where it calculates the new shape (pasted below for easy reference).

```py
    def get_output_shape(
        oldh: int, oldw: int, short_edge_length: int, max_size: int
    ) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        """
        Compute the output size given input size and target short edge length.
        """
        h, w = oldh, oldw
        size = short_edge_length * 1.0
        scale = size / min(h, w)
        if h < w:
            newh, neww = size, scale * w
        else:
            newh, neww = scale * h, size
        if max(newh, neww) > max_size:
            scale = max_size * 1.0 / max(newh, neww)
            newh = newh * scale
            neww = neww * scale
        neww = int(neww + 0.5)
        newh = int(newh + 0.5)
        return (newh, neww)
```

**So, in your case, you would be setting the *short_edge_length* to 720, and the *max_size* to 1280**. If you do that, referring to the code above, you will see that,

a) First, a scaling factor is calculated as 0.5 at the line `scale = size / min(h, w)`.

b) Then the new width and height are calculated as 1280, and 720 respectively at the line `newh, neww = size, scale * w`.

c) Lastly, the condition `if max(newh, neww) > max_size:` is not satisfied so a new scaling factor is not calculated and the new width and height are not updated.

Note that you can set the *max_size* higher than 1280 as well, and it will make no difference.
If you set it to lower than 1280 though, the condition referred to in (c) will be true, so a new scale is calculated and the new width and height are downscaled.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. @zepman I have images that are 1920*1440 and I am augmenting them with images of 160*140 , What do I set my min_size and max_size to?